# Do I need Devise callback if a CanCan callback is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, callback, controller, cancan

I'm currently in the process of securing my app so that ordinary users cannot create, edit, update, or destroy certain objects with the help of the CanCanCan gem. I also have Devise installed. Both gems provide callbacks so that users cannot perform certain actions unless a certain criteria is met.

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show] # Devise
  load_and_authorize_resource except: [:index, :show] # CanCanCan
end
```

In this particular case a user should only be able to have full access if they're an admin. I was wondering if it would be overkill to have both callbacks present in the controller.

The way I see it is if the user is not an admin and is trying to create an object then there would be no need to authenticate them. I wanted to be 100% sure in thinking and to ensure there were no sneaky workarounds a user could perform to gain access to these pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a need for both. The *Devise* callback will guarantee the user has signed up and it will throw an unauthenticated error if not. And *CanCanCan* will guarantee your user has the ability to do the changes or it will throw and Unauthorized error.

Right know both match, but later you might change your ability and then you shouldn't have to change the controller, it's better to have this from the beginning.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention it, but having two different errors allows you to can handle them differently. For example, ask an unauthenticated user to sign in and an unauthorized user to stop messing with your app (or simply log it)